# How can I format text in an HTML <textarea>?

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, textarea

I have a [<textarea>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) on my page, and when I click a button, the value of the text in the *textarea* is assigned to *.innerHTML* of a paragraph on my page.

Now let's say I type something like this in the *textarea*:

```
Hey
how's
it
going
?
```

The paragraph would look like this

```
Hey how's it going ?
```

Basically, it wouldn't have *<br>* tags at the end of each row. Is there a way I can force the JavaScript function to insert *<br>* tags at the end of each row of my textarea, or is there an easier way to do this?

JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById("sendMsgBtn").onclick = function(){
    var element = document.createElement("p");
    element.style.borderBottom = "1px solid black";
    var content = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("currentMsg").value);
    content = content.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
    element.appendChild(content);
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    document.getElementById("currentMsg").value = "";
}
```

Comment: `whatever.innerHTML = yourtext.replace('\n', '<br>');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want line breaks. Trust me.

Just set this:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

This CSS will make whitespace significant, preserving it as it was typed.

Answer (score 2):

When you copy the element from the textarea to the paragraph tag, replace all line breaks with `<br>` tags:

```
var input = document.getElementById("myTextarea").innerHTML; // get textarea contents
input = input.replace( /\n/g, "<br>"); // replace line breaks with <br> tags
document.getElementById("myParagraph").innerHTML = input; // place html-ified input into your <p>
```

Comment: Thanks! Umm can you explain why we didn't just do :

    input = input.replace( "\n", "<br>");

And what does /\n/g mean? I know what \n is.

Comment: @aCodingN00b Because that only replaces the first one. The `g` modifier makes it affect all matches, not just the first.

Comment: Umm it gives me an error when I try it : 

Uncaught TypeError: content.replace is not a function |

content is the variable with the value of the textarea box

Comment: Is the object you're working with definitely a string?

Comment: It's a text node with the value of the text in the textarea.

Comment: Hmm, well I don't know. Could you add the relevant code to your question?

Comment: Oh, you can't call the replace method on a text node; you have to call it on the text itself. Do something like `var value = document.getElementById("currentMsg").value; value = value.replace(/\n/g, "<br>"); var content = document.createTextNode(value);`

Comment: So basically just replace line breaks before creating the node? Thanks!

Comment: Another problem. Now my paragraph looks like this: 

Hey<br>how's<br>it<br>doing<br>?

Comment: Is that not what you intended? Also, perhaps @NiettheDarkAbsol's answer would be easier than mine for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't think you understood me. It literally looks like: Hey<br>how's<br>it<br>doing<br>?
I wanted this: 

Hey
how's
it
doing
?
With each new word starting at a new line.

Comment: Oh right, creating a text node will do that. My bad. Don't call "document.createTextNode" at all anywhere. Just directly execute `document.getElementById("myParagraph").innerHTML = value;` (using the same variable `value` from my earlier code sample)

Comment: Whoops. Formatting is bad here in the comments. Basically I want every new word to start at a new line, when I press "enter" while in a text box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86646/discussion-between-acodingn00b-and-oxguy3).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, try this:

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}
```

Then `nl2br(yourVariableWithContent);` can be used to change newline characters (the ones that the return button makes) into <br/>.

Comment: That aside, a better regex for matching line-breaks across platform (CR, LF, CRLF) would be `/(?=[\r\n])\r?\n?/` - I use it all the time ^_^

Comment: Woops I was typing something else while typing this :) No jQuery needed indeed.